# How can I serve pages at myapp.meteor.com/login

Tags: meteor

If I places two files in ./client, for example, ./client/myapp.html & ./client/login.html, the page http://localhost:3000/login.html didn't work.

if i place the login.html in ./client/login directory, the link http://localhost:3000/login didn't work too.

So, how can I serve pages at http://myapp.meteor.com/login

Comment: This solution works for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11749893/772481

Comment: [An example](http://router.meteor.com) that implements backbone router in meteor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Backbone to do the URL routing on the client side.

http://docs.meteor.com/#backbone

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router

Answer (score 4):

If you need server-side routing, the following provides a hacky but working solution:

```
__meteor_bootstrap__.app.stack.splice (0, 0, {
    route: '/hello',
    handle: function (req,res, next) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end("hello world");
        return;
    }.future ()
});
```

Now let's hope we don't have to use it for long before Meteor's official routing package is released!

Comment: This worked very well for my use case of allowing an external service to POST data to my app (such as a notification)

Answer (score 3):

Backbone routing is the way to go for the moment, as mentioned in a previous answer. I figured out how to use it in the context of Meteor by looking at the standard Todos app referenced on the Meteor site.

But I understand that it will be easier to write apps that are aware of the URL via an upcoming Routing release.

Answer (score 0):

I like the `router` package, available through Atmosphere with `mrt add router`.

https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router