# How do I create multi-page applications with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, url-routing, meteor

I am new to Javascript and just started fiddling around with Meteor out of curiosity. What really surprises me, is that it seems that all HTML content gets combined into a single page.

I suspect there is a way to introduce some handling of URLs directing to special pages. It seems that the "todo" example is capable of doing this via some kind of `Router` class. Is that the "canonical" way of URL handling?

Assuming I can handle URLs, how would I structure my HTML code to display separate pages? In my case they could each have completely separate sets of data, so no HTML code needs to be shared at all.

Comment: You should take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461097/meteorjs-routing-with-backbone-js

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501312/default-error-page/11513336#11513336

Comment: Hmm, these page elaborate on how to use `Backbone.Router`. It seems the HTML code is structured by wrapping contents in `{{#if route}}` directives, but that seems a little ... weird ... to me.

Comment: TO ALL VIEWING THIS QUESTION: The current solution is to use `Iron-Router`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Jon Gold's answer used to be correct, but [as of Meteor 0.5.4](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router#note):

> Work has now shifted to Iron Router. Please consider using IR instead of Router on new projects!

Thus, the current "canonical" way to do this is probably to use [IronRouter](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router).

Comment: currently best choice is to investigate [Angular](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/creating-an-app) and [React](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app) for Meteor.

Comment: @sfiore While support for Angular and React is a cool new addition, those are both _single_-page application frameworks. Unless you're able to pull off server-side rendering within meteor using the Angular or React routers (which I'm not sure is even possible), then these are not viable solutions for multi-page applications.

Answer (score 29):

As far as I am aware, there is currently no out of the box way to do this.

What I suggest to do, is to use Backbone.js smart package.
Backbone.js comes with the push-state Router, and if the user's browser doesn't support that it will fallback to hash urls.

In your meteor app directory type this `meteor add backbone`.

Then somewhere in your client-side code create a Backbone.js Router like so:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "":                 "main", //this will be http://your_domain/
    "help":             "help"  // http://your_domain/help
  },

  main: function() {
    // Your homepage code
    // for example: Session.set('currentPage', 'homePage');
  },

  help: function() {
    // Help page
  }
});
var app = new Router;
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
```

Then somewhere in your Handlebars template, you can create a helper that will render a page based on the value set in Session's "currentPage".

You can find more information about backbone.js router here: http://backbonejs.org/#Router

Also relevant information on how to create a Handlebars helper method in Metoer here: http://docs.meteor.com/#templates

Hope this helps.

Comment: Shouldn't that read `meteor add backbone`? Apart from that, I will possibly take a look around how to organise my HTML code with loads of if directives ...

Comment: Apologies! Yes it should be `meteor add backbone`. Thank you!

Comment: This is exactly bow I currently do it as well. Good answer.

Comment: You should take a look at my router smart package(https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) which is based off backbone's but does the wiring up for you (and a bit more).

Answer (score 26):

[Meteor-Router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) makes this really easy. I've been using it in some apps I've been building with Telescope as a good reference. Have a look at Telescope's [router.js](https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope/blob/master/client/lib/router.js)

To use it…

`mrt add router`

In client/router.js:

```
Meteor.Router.add({
  '/news': 'news', // renders template 'news'

  '/about': function() {
    if (Session.get('aboutUs')) {
      return 'aboutUs'; //renders template 'aboutUs'
    } else {
      return 'aboutThem'; //renders template 'aboutThem'
    }
  },

  '*': 'not_found'
});
```

In your template…

```
<body>{{renderPage}}</body>
```

Comment: So [Meteor-Router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) relies on [page-js](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/page-js), which relies on [page.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js) Node package? And after everything is installed I still get the error: `Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\packages\page-js\page-js\index.js'`. Where did it all go wrong?

Comment: I've got no idea, sorry - other than that I know Meteor doesn't officially support Windows at the moment.

Comment: Meteor does support with [Tom Wijsman's help](http://win.meteor.com/), but meteorite does not (that's why I don't really like that "yet-another-packaging" idea). However I can clone meteor-router and page-js from their repositories and create packages in Windows (well, folders and copy repositories' content into them). Any idea who might know?

Comment: Figured it out: just `npm install page` is not enough. I cloned the repo `git clone git://github.com/visionmedia/page.js.git` and copied it to the `.\Meteor\packages\page-js\page-js`

Comment: "0.5.4 is the last (non bugfix) release of router. Work has now shifted to Iron Router. "

Comment: To use this package, we can now use 'code' meteor add iron:router 'code'. No need to use meteorite now.

Answer (score 10):

I found the same problem. When the code gets bigger it is difficult to keep the code clean.

Here goes my approach to this problem:

I separate the different html pages as I would do with another web framework. There is an `index.html` where I store the root html page. And then for each big functional part I create a different template and place it in one different html. Meteor then merges them all. Finally I create a session variable called `operation` where I define what to show at each time.

Here goes a simple example

**index.html**

```
<head>
  <title>My app name</title>
</head>

<body>
 {{> splash}}
 {{> user}}
 {{> debates}}
</body>
```

then in **splash.html**

```
<template name="splash">
    {{#if showSplash}}
      ... your splash html code goes here...
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

then in **user.html**

```
<template name="user">
    {{#if showUser}}
      ... your user html code goes here...
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

and so on ...

In the javascript code then I check when to print each template using the Session variable, like this:

```
Template.splash.showSplash = function(){
    return Session.get("operation") == 'showSplash';
}
```

Finally the Backbone Router manages this Session variable

```
var DebateRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "": "showSplash",
    "user/:userId": "showUser",
    "showDebates": "showDebates",
    // ...
  },
  splash: function () {
   Session.set('operation', 'showSplash');
   this.navigate('/');
  },
  user: function (userId) {
   Session.set('operation', 'showUser');
   this.navigate('user/'+userId);
  },
  // etc...
});
```

I hope this pattern is helpful for other Meteor developers.

Answer (score 7):

This is my hacky solution to routing : 
https://gist.github.com/3221138

Just put the page name as the template name en navigate to /{name}

Comment: Nice idea, but doesn't that allow navigation to random "helper" templates?

Comment: You could prevent that by using an array containing the allowed pages,and else redirect to index.